Accessing Outlook Mail MIME Content Without Microsoft APIs: Is It Possible?
I'm currently developing an Outlook add-in and I'm looking to retrieve the MIME content of emails. Unfortunately, I'm encountering difficulty achieving this using JavaScript. While I understand that it's possible to retrieve it through API calls, I'm hoping to avoid this approach. In Outlook, we can access MIME content by clicking on an email and viewing its source. I'm wondering if there's a direct method to obtain this content programmatically. Additionally, if direct retrieval isn't feasible, is there a way to access all the information available in the MIME content using JavaScript?
Thanks for your assistance.

Firstly, Outlook and Exchange do not natively store messages in the MIME format, and there is no "View Source" in Outlook (are you thinking Gmail)?
You can get a message converted to MIME format using EWS or Graph API, and you are trying to avoid using an API (which one? all of them?), which only leaves you with a single option - construct the MIME source explicitly in your code one header/body/attachment at a time.
